# Very slow subqueries when using "NOT IN"

Tags: ms-access, query-optimization

I'm working on generating reports for data contained within a large pre-existing Access database (~500 mb after compact & repair), and I'm having trouble with a slow subquery.

The database has a big table which contains a record of every customer purchase. Here's a simple query which finds customers who have bought a blue widget. It completes within a few seconds and returns about ten thousand records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId 
FROM ProductSales
WHERE Product = 'BLUE'
```

Here's a query which tries to find customers who have bought a blue widget, but not a red widget. It takes about an hour to run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId FROM ProductSales
WHERE Product = 'BLUE' 
AND CustomerId NOT IN (
    SELECT CustomerId 
    FROM ProductSales 
    WHERE Product = 'RED'
)
```

Is there a way to refactor the second query to make it take a few minutes instead of an hour?

Comment: I presume the CustomerId field has indexes on it in both tables?

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId FROM ProductSales
WHERE Product = 'BLUE' minus SELECT CustomerId FROM ProductSales WHERE Product = 'RED'. I've seen cases where it really speeded up the query, but YMMV

Comment: @Marc B: There's only one table here, but CustomerId is indexed on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Access' database engine can't use an index for `Not In`, so it's bound to be slow.  With an index on CustomerId, this query should be much faster because the db engine can use the index.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT blue.CustomerId
FROM
    ProductSales AS blue
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT CustomerId 
            FROM ProductSales 
            WHERE Product = 'RED'
        ) AS red
    ON blue.CustomerId = red.CustomerId
WHERE
        blue.Product = 'BLUE'
    AND red.CustomerId Is Null;
```

You could probably also try a `Not Exists` approach, but index use there is not guaranteed.  Also, please see the comment below from David Fenton which discusses performance impact in more detail.

Comment: Woah. Down from 60 minutes to about a second. That's like 3600 times faster than the old version. Thanks! :-) For future reference, is there a list of SQL operations Access doesn't use the index for somewhere?

Comment: There probably is a list somewhere, but I don't know where.  :-)  If you want to go hardcore on this, Google Jet ShowPlan ... that will tell you authoritatively how/if the db engine is using indexes with your query.  You can find detailed discussion of query performance here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188211(office.10).aspx

Comment: It's not that NOT IN and NOT EXISTS never use the indexes -- it's that you can't predict when they will and when they won't. Any time you can re-engineer a NOT IN/EXISTS subquery into a JOIN, you'll likely improve performance. However, it all depends on editability of the resulting recordset -- some subqueries used in a JOIN will make the query non-updatable.

Comment: I've been waiting for years for Microsoft to sunset Access and JET, but they don't, so I have to keep digging up old gems like this one. The left join is simple, remembering this is the faster method is not.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index, of course, if you don't have one.  If that's a problem, it's probably just that there are lots of customers with orders for something other than RED but not so many with BLUE; this (untested) query tries to fix that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId FROM ProductSales
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId cid FROM ProductSales
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId
    FROM ProductSales
    WHERE Product = 'BLUE'
  ) foo ON CustomerId = cid
  WHERE Product = 'RED'
) bar USING (CustomerId)
WHERE cid IS NULL
```